# How to calculate $\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{k^2x^2}{x^4+k^4}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence

Real Analysis test, we were given the sequence of functions:
$$f_k(x)=\frac{k^2x^2}{x^4+k^4}$$
I checked pretty easily that it converges pointwise to $0$ everywhere and that it does not uniformly converge in $\mathbb R$. Last question was to check if the following limit was equal to zero:

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_k(x)dx=    \lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{k^2x^2}{x^4+k^4}dx$$
Surprisingly it is not, and it blows up to infinity. I managed to catch it by explicitly calculating the integral through Beta function, but I was not supposed to know that stuff.

Since we don't have uniform convergence on all of $\mathbb R$ we cannot swith the limit and the integral (which would give the result $0$ that is, indeed, wrong).

How would one find the result rapidly and without using special functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change variables using $x \rightarrow k u$. This gives
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{k^2 x^2}{x^4  +k^4}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{k^2 (k^2 u^2)}{k^4u^4  +k^4}(kdu) = k\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u^2}{u^4+1}du
$$
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty u^2/(u^4+1)du$ is clearly some positive constant independent of $k$. Thus, the limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$ must be $\infty$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{u^2}{u^4+1}\mathrm du=\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$